# How to upgrade SP2010 on-premise public website to SP2016 online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2016

We have a public facing SP2010 website on-premise, planning to upgrade to SP2016 online. Since MS depreciate SP public facing website, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a different hosting platform. This is described in the Microsoft Support Article ["SharePoint Online Public Websites to be discontinued"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3027254/sharepoint-online-public-websites-to-be-discontinued) and third party offerings are described on ["Website hosting partners for Office 365"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Website-hosting-partners-for-Office-365-47b10b76-315a-45a6-ad89-93ae2834d19d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)